# Pandas - A rolling cumulative count of distinct values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a df like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'date': ['01/01/2020', '01/01/2020', '01/01/2020', '02/01/2020', '02/01/2020', '03/01/2020', '03/01/2020'],
         'id': [101, 102, 103, 101, 104, 105, 106]
})
```

Output:

```
         date   id
0  01/01/2020  101
1  01/01/2020  102
2  01/01/2020  103
3  02/01/2020  101
4  02/01/2020  104
5  03/01/2020  105
6  03/01/2020  106
```

I require a cumulative count of the distinct values like so:

```
        date   id
0  01/01/2020  3
1  02/01/2020  4
2  03/01/2020  6
```

I have tried things like df.groupby(['date']).nunique() but obviously that's not right as it gives the unique count for each date, it doesn't have a rolling unique count as I require.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe is necesary first remove duplicates per `id` by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), then get counts per `date`s by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and add cumulative sum by  [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
df = df.drop_duplicates('id').groupby('date').size().cumsum().reset_index(name='id')
print (df)
         date  id
0  01/01/2020   3
1  02/01/2020   4
2  03/01/2020   6
```

Comment: That great thank you so much! I didn't think about dropping duplicates first.

Answer (score 3):

or we can use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
(~df.duplicated('id')).groupby(df['date']).sum().cumsum().rename('id').reset_index()

         date   id
0  01/01/2020  3.0
1  02/01/2020  4.0
2  03/01/2020  6.0
```

Comment: Thanks for providing an additional solution.